# How to use lkp override if mapping has two lkps?

Tags: informatica, lookup-tables

I have one src and 2 lkps. In the second lkp i want use lkp override.In the second lkp do ihave to join three tables.

sql query

```
SELECT IPF.ID,listagg(country_name,',') within group(order by(id))
 FROM 
Table1 RG INNER JOIN 
table2 IPF ON
RG.ID=IPF.ID
INNER JOIN table3 DR 
ON
DR.SDL_ID=RG.SDL_ID
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql overwrite. But you need to alias the columns and see if your query works in database. The sql you posted seems to be have incorrect group by so make sure it works first.
Sql should be

```
SELECT
 IPF.ID as id,listagg(country_name,',') within group(order by(id)) aggcntrname
 FROM Table1 RG INNER JOIN table2 IPF ON RG.ID=IPF.ID INNER JOIN table3 DR ON DR.SDL_ID=RG.SDL_ID group by id, sdl_id, country_name
Order by 1
--
```

Your lookup should have 2lookup ports and join ports.

```
in_id --input
id -- lkp port
aggcntrname --lkp and return port length 4000.
```

Join conditions will be on id = in_id. Sometime list agg produce more than 4000 char string and cause failure. Be careful about it.

Comment: SELECT IPF.ID,listagg(country_name,',') within group(order by(id)) ascountry_name FROM Table1 RG INNER JOIN table2 IPF ON RG.ID=IPF.ID INNER JOIN table3 DR ON DR.SDL_ID=RG.SDL_ID group by id;
Its working fine in db.

Comment: i modified the answer as per your comment.